# Vote MongoDB filtering method works on Compass, but not in Python - $and query

Tags: mongodb

:)

I am building a small app as a test of my skills with MongoDB, but the filtering method provided in the MongoDB docs (which btw works in Compass 100%) does not want to “cooperate” in GitPod…

I am trying to filter the results that have certain “category_name” AND “is_urgent” fields.
Following method filters and shows correct docs in Compass:

{ $and: [{“category_name”: (selected_category)}, {“is_urgent”: (urgent)}] }

but when I try to implement the same code in Python3 (using PyMongo) I get a syntax error at the $ sign.

```
@app.route(’/results’, methods=[‘POST’, ‘GET’])
def results():
selected_category = request.form[‘category_name’]
urgent = request.form[‘is_urgent’]
tasks = mongo.db.tasks.find.aggregate( { $and: [{“category_name”: (selected_category)}, {“is_urgent”: (urgent)}] } )
categories = mongo.db.categories.find()
return render_template(“tasks.html”, tasks=tasks, categories=categories)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khfOo.png)

Would you guys know is there any connection issues or syntax differences between Mongo Compass and PyMongo?

Comment: It's a python syntax error. Have you tried `"$and"` with quotes, instead of `$and` ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help! I did try to put the $and into the quotes and that did solve the syntax error, but still didnt access db correctly. I think I will take another training in MongoDB University to see / understand more... as I have posted the same tread in there as well and the reply I got is: "I suggest you take M121.You are missing some fundamental concepts and you will be much better served with the course than with any explications here.
But you can read about
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/